# Python: ones complement using join and lambda

Tags: python, join, lambda, pipeline, ones-complement

I am trying to create pipeline that converts a number to its Ones' complement number, for example (8)

> 1234 -> 7654
>
> 83743 -> 05145

I tried to create something in this style but I can't figure out how to build the pipeline correctly.

```
int(''.join((my_number(lambda y: 8-y, list(my_number)))))
```

Error

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Sorry, but a full error traceback would include the line of code also.

Comment: The part: my_number( is interpreted as a call of my_number. Surely not what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work:

```
int(''.join([str(8-int(y)) for y in str(my_number)]))
```

Example:

```
my_number=1258437620
```

Output:

```
>>> int(''.join([str(8-int(y)) for y in str(my_number)]))

7630451268
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to generate a number consisting of the digit 8 and of a length equal to that of the number to be converted:

```
for n in 1234, 83743, 1258437620:
    n_1s = int('8' * len(str(n))) - n
    print(f'{n} => {n_1s}')
```

```
1234 => 7654
83743 => 5145
1258437620 => 7630451268
```